# «Новые коты (А может быть, нет)» — оформление заголовка

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, заголовок, скобки

Скажите, пожалуйста, должна ли первая буква первого слова в заголовке быть большой, если это первое слово в этом-то заголовке находится в скобках?
Например (как правильно?):

*1) Новые коты (а может быть, нет)*

*2) Новые коты (А может быть, нет)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При оформлении *новокотовского* заголовка необходимо знать следующие правила:
[Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168);
[Скобки и другие знаки](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=179#pp179)

Я вижу здесь две возможности:

• *Новые коты (**а** может быть, нет)*
Это одно предложение, точек нет нигде, сочетание в скобках является вставкой и пишется со строчной буквы.

• *Новые коты. (**А** может быть, нет.)*
Первое предложение закончилось — ставится точка. Предложение в скобках становится самостоятельным, поэтому оно начинается с прописной буквы и заканчивается точкой.

Comment: Всегда указывайте, какой вариант лучше и почему. Но второй так себе, сомнительный. Два предложения в названии — это огромная редкость, не норма (не нормально). Для такого должны быть веские причины. Какие здесь? Сомнение обозначается вводными словами, не новыми предложениями. Можно заменить на "не факт" (и это лучше).

Comment: Ещё дело в том, что когда одно предложение в скобках, то нет равноправия, второе предложение в названии явно не должно быть вставочным, они должны быть на одном уровне ("сегментирование", "парцелляция" у Розенталя). Считаю это неудачным вариантом (первая причина в других комментариях). А первый вариант одобряю.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнительный** ответ (на комментарий)

• Требование: *Всегда указывайте, какой вариант лучше и почему.*
**Ответ:** ни-ка-кой.
Смысл вопроса был в том, **как** *пунктуационно* грамотно оформить заголовок **со скобками**. Именно на этот вопрос я и ответила (мне думается, что правильно).

• Мнение: *Два предложения в названии — это огромная редкость, не норма (не нормально).*
**Ответ:** я специально дала розенталевскую ссылку.
А в ней имеются такие примеры (получается, что прямо-таки огромно редкие?):
*Жить вечно. Возможно ли?

С дипломом? Не требуется

Подписать? Пожалуйста!

Без печати? Недействительно…

Эстрада. Она всегда волнует

Удача. И какая!*

• Конечно же, предлагаемый заголовок можно написать по-другому, без скобок (кстати, вот именно **их** [скобок] я ни разу в заголовках и не встречала).
Но ведь это уже совершенно другой вопрос, не правда ли?
И — чтобы развеять сомнения — нужно, считаю, обязательно дать читателю понять, **к чему** относится сочетание *или нет* — к слову "новые" или к слову "коты".
**Варианты:**
Новые коты. Или не новые?
Новые коты! Или не коты?
Коты новые или нет?
Коты! Новые или нет?

• Дополнительно к дополнительному (о редкостях):

```
  ОТ «УТРА СТРЕЛЕЦКОЙ КАЗНИ» К «МЕНШИКОВУ
  В БЕРЕЗОВЕ». НАКОПЛЕННЫЙ ОПЫТ И НОВЫЕ ЗАДАЧИ
```

[Точка в середине и конце заголовка](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/)

Comment: Римма, отличный доп!

Comment: Спасибо. Поклоны уже были. Теперь — книксен.

Comment: То есть вы перекладываете проблему выбора на спрашивающего. Ясно. Да видел вашу ссылку. Но ни в журналах, ни в газетах, ни на сайтах такого нет (не вижу). Никогда такого не видел! Ни разу! Может, такое было популярно при Розентале. Это, наверно, один случай на тысячу. Ну вы пример изменили, уже нет подчинения одной фразы другой. Это уже фантазии на тему.

Comment: Считаю, что крайне важно указывать, какой вариант лучше — чтобы спрашивающий понимал, какой вариант ему лучше использовать. А указание причины поможет ему определять самому в похожих случаях.

Comment: Но я ведь уже ответила — никакой. В крохотном заголовке с таким смыслом скобки не нужны.

Comment: Аа. А я тоже понял буквально. Что не хотите отвечать, поскольку не считаете нужным, так как об этом не спрашивалось (ниже написано). Но здесь фраза подчиняющаяся, на отдельную мысль она не тянет, как "не факт", "это не точно", "наверно". В ваших вариантах уже да.

Comment: Всегда какой-то из вариантов лучше. Поэтому не понял "никакой".

Comment: Но всё равно вам и другим надо знать, что это очень важно. А то надают вариантов, и разбирайся сам.

Comment: А Pumpkin'у-то всё равно таки на все-то ваши таки измышления-то!!!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да, человек не умеет благодарить.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Четко и красиво ты нас поддел, Саша, с *частичными-то* кружевами!.. Но ведь тебе, вижу, не все равно. Может, и еще кому?.. Устала я уже защищаться — от почти хамского давления, от комментариев в приказном тоне и всяких-прочих "напрыгов". Надо, наверно, сделать перерыв.

Comment: Нет, Римма, не надо перерывов! И так никого нет, совы вы мудрые. Нападения, защита... – всё очень интересно!

Answer (score 1):

**Второй дополнительный** ответ

**1.** Если кто-то чего-то ни разу не видел, то это не означает, что этого нет (пример со Стрелецкой казнью, кстати, взят из "Справочника издателя и автора" Мильчина и Чельцовой).

Вот современные заголовки (они никак не могли быть популярны при Розентале):
Как спасти Россию. Совет казахского аксакала
Кто такие япстеры. И почему вы один из них
Ситуация в мире накаляется. Что делать инвесторам?
Мобильная атака. Чем опасен мобильник?
Кто правит миром. Экскурс в конспирологию
Надоело все! Что делать, если не хочешь учиться?

**2.** Когда в дополнительном ответе я написала, что ни разу в заголовках не встречала скобок, то имела в виду заголовки "малоемкого" размера, как в вопросе.
В длинных же заголовках (чаще всего — научных статей), конечно же, скобки есть.

Вот примеры из монографии Э. М. Рянской и Л. В. Алексеевой:
• Хроника Великой Победы (1941–1945)
• Миф о провинциальном историке в XX в. (на примере С. И. Архангельского)
• ”Ласковый телок двух маток сосет”: к вопросу о природе украинской государственности во второй половине XVII — первой трети XVIII в. (в порядке дискуссии с Т. В. Чухлибом)
• Вновь среди “градодержателей” Сибири... (К истории воеводского управления на восточной окраине России в конце XVI–XVII вв.)
• **1000 миль за полтора года? (Кем было начато присоединение Сибири к России)**

**3.** Вот! Вот, собственно, над чем стоит подумать и из-за чего стоит спорить.
Обратите внимание, что в последнем заголовке точки внутри скобок нет.
Но ведь и во всех правилах об этой *внутренней точке*, об этом *особенном* случае — ни слова.

[Прагматический компонент заголовков научных текстов (на примере англо- и русскоязычных публикаций по истории)](https://nvsu.ru/ru/Intellekt/2279/Ryanskaya,_EH.M.,_Alekseeva,_L.V._Pragmaticheskijj_komponent1.pdf)

Comment: А кто вам говорит, что это означает, что такого нет?! Это означает, что такое бывает очень редко.

Comment: "Дык" Вы же сами и написали: *Но ни в журналах, ни в газетах, ни на сайтах такого нет (не вижу).*

Comment: Там специально "не вижу" в скобках, чтобы была понятной мысль. Ещё думал, как сформулировать — чтобы не поняли буквально. Так говорят о чём-то редком. Нет в порядке вещей...

Comment: То есть не вижу, чтобы такое было, но оно где-то есть, прячется, как суслик.