# Точка внутри скобок в заголовке: ставить ли её?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция, заголовок, точка

Как правильно оформить этот заголовок? (Это важно.)

> Орфононимы: что это такое и с чем их едят? (К съедению не рекомендованы.)

> Орфононимы: что это такое и с чем их едят? (К съедению не рекомендованы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Точка перед закрывающей скобкой не ставится.* Разве?

Думаю, что вопрос возник вот отсюда:
[«Новые коты (А может быть, нет)» — оформление заголовка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473823/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%90-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

> • **1000 миль за полтора года? (Кем было начато присоединение Сибири к России)**
>
> **3.** Вот! Вот, собственно, над чем стоит подумать и из-за чего стоит спорить.
> Обратите внимание, что в последнем заголовке точки внутри скобок нет.
> Но ведь и во всех правилах об этой *внутренней точке*, об этом *особенном* случае — ни слова.

• Я бы поставила точку в заголовке из вопроса, а в цитируемом мною заголовке — вопросительный знак:

*Орфононимы: что это такое и с чем их едят? (К съедению не **рекомендованы.)***
*1000 миль за полтора года? (Кем было начато присоединение Сибири к **России?)***

> [**§ 99.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128) Вставная конструкция, будучи самостоятельным предложением или частью текста (ряд предложений), относящаяся к абзацу (текст вставки после открывающей скобки начинается с прописной буквы), выделяется **скобками**. Перед скобкой, открывающей вставку, ставится необходимый по условиям контекста знак конца предложения. Перед закрывающей скобкой ставится знак, фиксирующий конец вставного предложения: *...Так будет дальновиднее... **(У Маслова клокотало в горле, хотя говорит он тихо и даже вяло.)***...

•• Если в скобках находится законченное повествовательное предложение, то в конце него **должна стоять точка**. Она находится перед закрывающей скобкой — ею, собственно скобкой, и заканчивается заголовок (**скобкой**, а не точкой).
Это, мне кажется, никаким правилам не противоречит. Просто *такой* — повторю, особенный — случай в правилах не рассмотрен.

Comment: То есть в итоге ставить точку?

Comment: Ну да. А почему нет-то? Ведь заголовок заканчивается **скобкой**, а не точкой.

Comment: А я и не союи6рался спорить. Я просто спросил итог. Разве я сказал "нет"?

Comment: Ой! Какое же у вас смешное слово случайно получилось — "союи6рался"... У нас, *в Европах*, сегодня — канун Рождества. Здоровья и добра желаю всем, всем!

Answer (score 1):

Точка перед закрывающей скобкой не ставится (поправка: нашёл правило, но выглядит избыточно. Я бы не рекомендовал). В конце заголовка точка  не ставится. Поэтому рекомендую вариант без точки

Comment: Почему перед закрывающей не ставится? Если новое предложение — это вставная конструкция целиком, то перед закрывающей скобкой ставится точка.

Comment: В случае сокращений  — согласен. В других  — да, нашёл такое правило, но выглядит чудовищно. Дополню ответ